# What is the fastest way to consume an JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, get, seo, axios

I call a JSON with 7000 objects *(I use the JS filter direct in the GET's scope and keep the response in a variable)* by GET's *axios* and as you can see from the image it's taking too long, affecting **SEO** :(

[It's **3 seconds** delay!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Dla.jpg)

**I've done something:**

*I packed JSON with gzip*

*I used minify* in the JSON*

*I put cookies for 1 year on htacess*

*I put the direct filter on the GET call*

**Things I want to do but I am unsure and I need your help:**

*Use Algolia*

*Split JSON into parts*

Can anyone help me please i can't find the answer is i have been looking for this for **months** :(((

Comment: Stop sending so much JSON? Send only a small amount and make a few more requests when needed?

Comment: Hi thx for the aswer... I have 5 category filters in the axios call each returns 6 objects to display... If the filter returns less than 6 I make another axios call and merge the results? Its is a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement pagination on your backend to send JSON in smaller peaces or open an stream to read the JSON string and parse it as it's comes

Comment: Thank all guys I am thinking about split in 10 parts... 
1mb = 3 seconds
0,1 mb = 300 ms (0.3 seconds)
Its is a good way to go?
If my filter don't get the total objects needed ? Save the result and make another axios call and merge them? I have 5 category filters that return minimun 6 objects to display in my home page ;)